# Vector animation in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, objectanimator, android-vectordrawable

**Preface**
I want to implement a download animation in RecyclerView. In *onBindViewHolder* and *onViewRecycled* I subscribe to and unsubscribe from presenter which retrieves the percentage of already downloaded file.
I start animation:

```
        AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat drawable = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(context, R.drawable.download_animated);
        if (drawable != null) {
            holder.downloadingIcon.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            drawable.start();
        }
```

**Problem**
I have got *onViewRecycled* invoked right after the animation is finished with follow stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
at EventRecyclerViewAdapter.onViewRecycled(EventRecyclerViewAdapter.java:271)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.dispatchViewRecycled(RecyclerView.java:6064)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.addViewHolderToRecycledViewPool(RecyclerView.java:5835)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleViewHolderInternal(RecyclerView.java:5800)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.removeAnimatingView(RecyclerView.java:1305)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimatorRestoreListener.onAnimationFinished(RecyclerView.java:11775)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator.dispatchAnimationFinished(RecyclerView.java:12275)
at android.support.v7.widget.SimpleItemAnimator.dispatchChangeFinished(SimpleItemAnimator.java:304)
at android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator$7.onAnimationEnd(DefaultItemAnimator.java:363)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatJB$1.onAnimationEnd(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatJB.java:51)
at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator$AnimatorEventListener.onAnimationEnd(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:1121)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1149)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1309)
at android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(AnimationHandler.java:146)
at android.animation.AnimationHandler.-wrap2(AnimationHandler.java)
at android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame(AnimationHandler.java:54)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:957)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:667)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

**Question**
Why it behaves like so and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, *notifyItemChanged* caused to recycler previous ViewHolder so *onBindViewHolder* and *onViewRecycled* are invoked... but on different instances. Firstly *onBindViewHolder* is invoked with **new** ViewHolder instance. Next *onViewRecycled* is invoked with the **old** ViewHolder.
 In my case problem was relying only on one **id** of the model. It doesn't unambiguously describe Presenter's View I used to notify about updates.